# how do I make these images scattered over the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know where I got wrong in typing the code
so here's the code...

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Coords:
    def __init__(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2

    def within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 > co2.x1 and co1.x1 < co2.x1:
            return True
        elif co1.x2 > co2.x1 and co1.x2 < co2.x2:
            return True
        elif co2.x1 > co1.x1 and co2.x1 < co1.x1:
            return True
        elif co2.x2 > co1.x1 and co2.x2 < co1.x1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
def within_y(co1, co2):
    if (co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2) \
       or (co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2)\
       or (co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y1) \
       or (co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y1):

        return True
    else: 
        return False


def collided_right(co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x2 >= co2.x1 and co1.x2 <= co2.x2:
            return True
        return False
def collided_top(co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.y1 <= co2.y2 and co1.y1 >= co2.y1:
            return True

    return False


def collided_bottom(co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        y_calc = co1.y2 + y
        if y_calc >= co2.y1 and y_calc <= co2.y2:
            return True
        return False


def collided_left(co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 <= co2.x2 and co1.x1 >= co2.x1:
            return True
        return False
class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Mr. Stick Man Races for the Exit")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
                             highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="backround.gif")
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
                                         image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.Running = True
 
    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.Running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.01)



class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.endgame = False
        self.coordinates = None

    def move(self):
        pass
    def coords(self):
        return self.coordinates

class PlatformSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
                                              image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + width, y + height)
            
g = Game()
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="Large.gif"), \
                           0, 480, 100, 10)
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="Large.gif"), \
                           150, 440, 100, 10)
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="Large.gif"), \
                           300, 400, 100, 10)

g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.mainloop()
```

it should come over the screen like this...
[image]

but it comes like this
[image]

Comment: You used same variable `platform1` for the three `PlatformSpite`, so it only reference the last instance.  Therefore, you append same instance of `PlatformSpite` three times.

Comment: I am sorry, But I do not understand

Comment: He means to say that your using same variable `platform1` for three instances of `PlatformSprite`, line 114 and appending all those same items onto the list 3 times.

Comment: ohh thnks for the help!

Comment: To fix your problem, you should use different names for the three `PlatformSpite`, for example `platform1`, `platform2` and `platform3`.  Also you should not use while loop as your `mainloop()`.  Try using `after()` and `tkinter.mainloop()` together instead.